# Dax Measure with multiple filters and all

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a table that has the following structure:

- Order
- State
- Order Date
- Order Finished
- Department
- Area
- Value

This table is linked to the calendar table through the column [Order Finished].
Now I would like to get every order - regardless the Order Finished Date with this filters:

1. State = > 16 && <> 20 <= 99
2. Department = Drilling
3. Area = FT1

Bow how?
This approach is not working:

```
CALCULATE ( SUM ( tbl[Value]),
ALL ( Calendar),
tbl[Department] = "Drilling",
tbl[Area] = "FT1",
tbl[Status] > 16 && <> 20 && <=99 )
```

Here is a screenshot of the tabel:
[image]

Comment: your syntax looks OK, but I've noticed that your description refers to `State` while your code uses `Status`, can that be the issue?

Comment: What is your expected output from this sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below code-

```
total_value = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM (tbl[Value]),
    ALL (Calendar),
    ALLEXCEPT(tbl,Department),
    tbl[Department] = "Drilling",
    tbl[Area] = "FT1",
    tbl[Status] > 16,
    tbl[Status] <> 20,
    tbl[Status] <=99
)
```

If you need department wise different results, you should not have that department filter in the code as shown below-

```
total_value = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM (tbl[Value]),
    ALL (Calendar),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(tbl,Department),
        && tbl[Area] = "FT1",
        && tbl[Status] > 16,
        && tbl[Status] <> 20,
        && tbl[Status] <=99
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! But it is not working. I have a matrix listed with all departments. Now I get for every department the same number.

Comment: Best option please share some sample data and your expected output from them.

Comment: Thank you! But it is still not working. I get an error since I need to add an aggregation.

Comment: is the name of the column State or Status ?